# How to pass model to @html.partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've used IEnumerable in the main view and and single model object in partial view.

I'm doing CRUD operation: Each row has edit/details/delete buttons.

Below is my CSHTML code:

```
@model IEnumerable<jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default" ,href = "#modalEdit" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default", href = "#modalDetails" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "modal-with-form btn btn-default", href = "#modalDelete" })             



            <div id="modalEdit" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                @Html.Partial("Edit", item)
            </div>

            <div id="modalDetails" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                @Html.Partial("Details", item)
            </div>


            <div id="modalDelete" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                @Html.Partial("Delete", item)
            </div>




        </td>
    </tr>
```

Clicking on edit/details/delete affects only the first row in the table.

The model in the partial view I used is:

```
@model jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User
```

How do I overcome this?

my controller

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.User.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(user);
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Message"] = "Data has been updated successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using MVC pattern, you must to pass data from controller (C) to view (V), normally after obtain them from model (M). So you have to code a controller with this approach:

```
public ActionResult your_partial_view() 
{
  // Do your magic. Obtain data from model, handle them and after pass them to the view (Partial view in this case)
  return PartialView("your_partial_view", jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User);
}
```

You should define your class jQuery_CRUD.DAL.User in your model as well.

The name of the controller must be the same of the folder into View-layer-folders in pattern. And the method must be the name of your view or partial view.

If you want to learn about it, I recommend you these tutos: [official´s tutos](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

By the other hand, you have in my git a few working´s demo, Check it out: [MVC working´s demo](https://github.com/EliasMerabet/Net/tree/master/Basic-Examples-MVC)

Let me know any doubt you could have.

Cheers.

Comment: i've added controller...can u please look at it

Comment: What is the name for your controller? As far as I have seen should be EditController, and your method inside it Edit as well... Did you debug it? Are you entering in your first method (first time when you are loading the page)? Are you entering in the second method (after submit, second time)?

Comment: controller name is UserController

Comment: Your problem is when you are routing to the different controllers and methods. In ActionLink, first parameter should be ControllerName, second one should be action name.

Comment: By the other hand Html.Partial, is looking for the Partial view in the current folder, after it will check shared folder... You could call a partial view in another folder following the path in your call.

Comment: the first parmeter is not controller name...it is link text

Comment: Yep, sorry. I´m programming now in other languages and I was trying to explain you without check it. Anyway, is working now? Did you find the error?

Comment: Did you change your routing? Which error you are seeing?

Comment: @NaveenVijayan How is it going? If you think my approach help you, Do you mind to rate my answer? Thanks mate.